# Prove that there exists a differentiable function $g$ with $g(f(x)) = x$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, proof-writing

Let $f : V \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and differentiable function. Let $a$ be in the domain of $f$ with $f'(a) \neq 0$. Prove that there exist two intervals $I, J \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and a differentiable function $g : J \rightarrow I$ with $$g(f(x)) =x$$
 for all $x \in I$ and 
$$f(g(y)) = y$$
 for all $y \in J$.
Since $f$ is continuous and differentiable I was thinking about the mean value theorem, but I am not sure how to use this theorem.

Comment: If $f$ is continuously differentiable then this is just the Inverse Function Theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove it, since it is false. Take, for instance,$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x+2x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $f'(0)=1$, but there is no open interval $I$ such that $0\in I$ and that the restriction of $f$ to $I$ is injective.